# Count in lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda

I am trying to run a query where I get the name of locations and the number of items in that location. So if i have a program that contains 3 locations I want to know how many programs are in that location..I need to use this with a lambda expression or linq to entities.

```
return Repository.Find(x => x.Location.Name.Count())...clearly missing something here.
```

we'll just assume I have a Program entity with ProgramID, ProgramName, LocationName...need to know how many programs are in at a location

Comment: Dude! You have to start clicking Accepted Answer on your questions! Makes it so much easier for everyone else, and it's the way this site works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
return repository.Count(x => x.Location == "SomeLocation");
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to know the counts for all locations at once?

```
var locCounts = Repository.GroupBy(prog => prog.Location.Name).ToLookup(g => g.key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: Matt...thanks for the help, this seems to work. The application throws an exception though and Im struggling to fix the issue. When I changed the return type to ILookup<> I went through my entire application and changed all the appropriate methods to look for and call ILookup. But I am not getting this error –  The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error. Im sure this is quite tough for you to have an opinion of the fix..but wanted to pass this along...

Comment: what were you return types before? it shouldn't be hard to get my above code to give out the right type.

Answer (score 0):

if you will repositoryPattern, use this code

```
Clients.Where(p => p.DateOfArrival >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) && p.DateOfArrival <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)).Select(p => p.ID).Count()
```

[Repository Pattern](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Where did DateOfArrival come from? As far as I see, there isn't any mention or requirement of such column. I hope you haven't just copy-pasted your code.

Comment: DateOfArrival is my entity column (type is datetime).